# Forecasting with 2 time series with inequal lenght and frequency

Tags: model, transformation, seasoned-schemer

I have 2 time series.
1) monthly residential natural gas demand from 2013 to 2016
2) daily average temperature from 2013 to 31/03/2017

I have to provide a monthly and daily prediction of the residential natural gas demand for the period January 2017 to April 2017.

After having prepared the data handling NaN and Na, I have to transform the temperature in average
 monthly temperature. Then I should build the model to estimate the future values of the demand.

I am quite new in R and in econometrics.

Which transformation can I use in R to transforme the daily average temperature time series in 
monthly average temperature time series?

Is vector autocorrelation a good model for seasonal data?
 I should use the temperature and the old demand values to predict the future demand.